# JMeter BeanShell Echo Request

Tags: regex, json, jmeter, string-literals, beanshell

I am trying to simplify a series of tests where I copy a long string of JSON that's sent to a server for execution which has several UUID's embedded in them that I need to know.  I'm trying to run assertions on the response, but need some of the UUID's in order to read the correct return value.

The JSON strings are very long, and it would be very tedious to go into every single one that I want to run an assertion for and identify the correct UUID, so I'm wanting to use RegEx to basically parse out the request data and pull the correct UUID i need to look for into a JMeter variable, which I can then use for future testing.

I can't find a way to use RegEx on request data, which makes sense because NORMALLY you know exactly what you are requesting.  In my case, I don't (or rather from the program's view I do, but I, as a person, don't ).

My work around is to build a beanshell echo script which would allow me to put the long JSON string into a variable, which I would then send directly to the Response Data, which I could then use RegEx on.

Example:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(${jsonData});
SampleResult.setDataType(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT);
```

The main problem I am having is that the JSON is interlaced with a TON of characters which would need to be escaped (tons of double quotes, for instance).

Is there a way to get around this by perhaps treating all of the JSON as a string literal?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very recommended to use Beanshell/BSF+javascript, especially for large amounts of data and high loads. I would rather go for one of the following approaches:

1. Regular Expression Extractor can be applied to a JMeter Variable directly:

[image: Regular Expression Variable]

2. You can use [Dummy Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)), you can set both request and response in it.
3. If you still want to use scripting approach for any reason, consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler and "groovy" language](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).

Comment: it's not intended for large loads, more for regression testing in my particular case. The problem with that is that I still would not be able to use the regex against the request.  That applies the results to the variable, not what it's testing against

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Beanshell, I used a BSF Sampler using javascript, then wrote the following:

```
SampleResult = '${jsonVar}';
```

Since the JSON model does not use single quotes.  It then echoes out to response data where I can do the regex.

Conversely I could have just done the REGEX test within javascript, but since I already had the expression written within a jmeter RexEx extractor I chose this route.